# Probabilty Question. Question no. 29 IGCSE June 2018

Tags: probability

There are two boxes A and B. Each of them contain 1 white bead and 7 green beads.
A student picks at random two beads from Box A and puts them in Box B.
Again, he picks at random two beads from Box B and puts them in Box A.
Find the probability that Box A still contains **1** white bead and **7** green beads

My workings:

Probability of picking 2 green beads from A : (7/8 x 7/7)=7/8

Probability of picking 1 white bead and 1 green bead from A: (1/8 x 7/7)+ (7/8 x 1/7)=1/4

Probability of picking 2 green beads from B : (7/8 x 7/7)=7/8

Probability of picking 1 white bead and 1 green bead from B : (1/8 x 7/7)+ (7/8 x 1/7)=1/4

Probability of Box A still having 1 white bead and 7 green beads : (1/4 x 1/4) + (7/8 x 7/8 ) = 53/64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:
$$(\overbrace{P(W_1,G_2)+P(G_1,W_2)}^{A(1W,7G)})\cdot (\overbrace{P(W_1,G_2)+P(G_1,W_2)}^{B(2W,8G)})=\\
\left(\frac18\cdot \frac77+\frac78\cdot \frac17\right)\cdot \left(\frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac89+\frac{8}{10}\cdot \frac29\right)=\frac{4}{45};\\
(\overbrace{P(G_1,G_2)}^{A(1W,7G)})\cdot (\overbrace{P(G_1,G_2))}^{B(1W,9G)})=\\
\left(\frac78\cdot \frac67\right)\cdot \left(\frac{9}{10}\cdot \frac89\right)=\frac{3}{5}.$$
Hence:
$$\frac{4}{45}+\frac{3}{5}=\frac{31}{45}.$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

- What happens if he originally picked 2 green beads?
- What happens if he originally picked 1 white and 1 green?
- What are the probabilities of each of these cases happening?

Comment: Well i tried all of the things you mentioned during my examination yesterday and I got an answer of 53/64.
I would be delighted if you would kindly provide the workings.

Comment: Oh and i edited and showed the workings above.